# Round robin read requests to Redis slaves

Tags: redis, jedis

We have a single redis instance that stores about 6 hashes, where each hash contains about 500-700 keys each(business objects). I am planning to setup a master slave architecture wherein I can have a single master instance with 2 slaves, and I want to round robin read requests to the slaves. I have been looking for ways to do this but in so far in my quest I've been unable to figure out how to do it. We use Jedis as our redis client. Is it possible to round robin read requests to a slave?(Ofcourse, I know that there might be a time window where the data is inconsistent in the slaves, and I'm willing to sacrifice that)

Help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is the first time that I'm trying to setup a distributed architecture. So please bear with me if what I say seems ignorant.

Comment: Can you not just choose a slave randomly client-side?

Comment: Right now, as the number of slave instances would be limited, sure I can. Infact that is the approach that I'm gonna use for now. However, what if I have upto 6-7 slave instances? Wouldn't then I have to maintain a connection pool and timeouts for each of these instances?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on the client side which can be hard to manage. Some other idea's:

- Use a load balancer like HAproxy to manage it, be careful as this might introduce a single point of failure.
- If you're on AWS you could use an ELB
- You could use DNS round robin for this (assuming you have enough client nodes to balance because of DNS cache)

If you do decide on client side there are quite some tools available that can help you with solving the service location problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am just wondering though, what is the best practice regarding this? I mean, I've searched google and it seems that there is no consensus on the best/standard approach on doing this.

Comment: I wasn't aware that HaProxy supported Redis protocol. But then again one would have to connect with HaProxy using TCP . This is probably the best way to go I think.